# Programmatic inclusion of CSS pages from JavaScript breaks styiling image url

Tags: javascript, html, css, xmlhttprequest, stylesheet

Directory structure:

```
html/index.html  
html/css/css.css  
html/css/img/avatar.png
```

content of css.css:

```
body {
  background-image: url("./img/avatar.png");    
}
```

If inside index.html the css.css file is included using "link" tag it works OK and avatar.png is displayed as page background:

```
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="./css/css.css">
```

However if JavaScript code is used to include the css.css file then console shows error:

```
function load_css(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4)
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var oNew = document.createElement('style');
      oNew.rel = 'STYLESHEET';
      oNew.type = 'text/css';
      oNew.textContent = xhr.responseText;
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(oNew);
    }
  }
  xhr.open("GET", './css/css.css', false);
  xhr.send(null);
}

load_css();
```

Console:

```
GET http://localhost/html/img/avatar.png 404 (Not Found)
```

it doesn't work in all browsers.

It appears that when a CSS file is included programmatically using the above method then relative links inside that CSS become relative in respect to the HTML file that included them instead of the CSS file which contains them.

Any suggestions for a remedy?

Comment: Use an absolute path to your CSS document.

Comment: Additionally, I don't know what `/html/` on your setup but it looks like you're one folder short. My setup with XAMPP is `http://localhost/*site-folder*/yadayada`

Answer (score 1):

## Causes the problem:

If you use `<link>`, the file path is done with 2 Levels:

- 1 level: place where is your "html".
- 2 level: place where is your "css" files.

If you enter "css" via "javascript", the path will have only 1 level, in other words, with javascript css would be equal to the same folder as your "html".

---

## As HTTP requests for static files and dynamic work plays

Javascript is "static things" become "dynamic", but when inserting an element within the "HTML requests" even understand like a call from a static file (in this case as if you've been using up the `<style>`).

---

## Possible solutions

### 1 - Use absolute paths

So the solution is you use the "absolute path" for images called by CSS, example:

`background-image: url(http://website.com/css/img/avatar.png);`

or

`background-image: url(http://website.com/html/css/img/avatar.png);`

### 2 - Use String.replace

Another possible solution is to use `String.replace` in Javascript, see:

```
function RelativeToAbsolute(a){
    var b = String(window.location).replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, "").replace(/\/$/, "")+"\/css/";
    if(a){
        a = String(a);
        a = a.replace(/url\(((http|https|file[:]\/\/)[:]\/\/)/gi, "url(!$1");//block next replace in absolute paths (if absolute paths to your css)
        a = a.replace(/url\([.]\//gi, "url({PATH}");//define replace for paths like "./css/img/"
        a = a.replace(/url\(([a-z])/gi, "url({PATH}$1");//define replace for paths like "css/img/"
        a = a.replace(/url\(\{PATH\}([^)]+[)])/gi, "url("+b+"$1");//set absolute path
        a = a.replace(/url\([!]((http|https|file[:]\/\/)[:]\/\/)/gi, "url($1");//replace "!" in absolute paths (if absolute paths to your css)
        myLOG(a);
        return a;
    } else {
        myLOG("CSS invalid");
    }
    return a;
}
...
//With your CSS
oNew.textContent = RelativeToAbsolute(xhr.responseText);
```

### 3 - CACHE: Use .htaccess (or equivalent) for cache static files

When accessed with ajax css file will be added to the cache.

When the css file is accessed with `<link href="">` it will already be in the cache.

Your .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
#1 year
ExpiresDefault A29030400
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Your javascript:

```
function load_css(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = './css/css.css';
  xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4)
    if (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 304) {//304 not modified
      var oNew = document.createElement('link');
      oNew.rel = 'stylesheet';
      oNew.type = 'text/css';
      oNew.href = url;
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(oNew);
    }
  }
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);//use async
  xhr.send(null);
}

load_css();
```

---

**Tip:**

Something good for your server would use images with CDN (eg. sub-domains with "image." prefix), example:

`background-image: url(http://images.website.com/css/img/avatar.png);`

or

`background-image: url(http://images.website.com/html/css/img/avatar.png);`

Comment: I am using a bunch of CSS files which are part of a JS Framework. It is many files with existing code. I'm looking for a solution on JavaScript script level.

Comment: @Gonki It's like I said when you insert the "css" using "javascript", it is as if you use up `<style>`. So the best solution at this point perhaps modify your css.

Comment: I modified CSS hoping it would be a temporary remedy. If I place an html file that includes modified css into another directory then those updates become invalid. I would very much like to avoid changing CSS files in this case because they are a part of a popular JS Framework.

Comment: @Gonki If the images are using absolute path, do not understand how this can fail? Not the css to have to have absolute path is images.I edited my answer.

Comment: if absolute path is used there is a problem with distribution. In my case right now the relative path is localhost. I want my code when downloaded to be ready for use with the existing JS Framework without tinkering with the framework's extensive CSS code.

Comment: Ok I thought me something you can use in javascript you can use "string.replace", so you can use relative paths and javascript convert to absolute path, I will try to add an example.

Comment: it's not a great idea because it noticeably slows page load time. I was hoping to discover a createElement() feature but unable to find anything so far.

Comment: Indeed with `document.createElement` you will not meet your goal, what is the javascript does things "staticas" become "dynamic", but requests will be executed as if it were static css (using only html).

So either you use absolute path (eg. with `String.replace`)

**OR** you edit your CSS so that the call images like this: `background: url(css/img/img1.jpg)`. NOTE: I edit my answer.

Comment: I don't like string.replace in this case because it makes CPU usage jump when loading pages but for lack of a better solution I may end up adopting it. Hoping a better solution may be found.

Comment: Note: your use `xhr.open("GET", url, false);`, but your code use `onload`, therefore prefer asynchronous mode `xhr.open("GET", url, true);` :)

Comment: I think it's a good idea. Another option is to try search and replace on files so they are updated with absolute links on disk.

Comment: @Gonki, all images are in a specific directory? eg.: www/images/theme1 and www/images/theme2, in others words, are in www/images/* ?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a **synchronous** `XMLHttpRequest` to inject CSS into a `<style>` element? You can just create a new `<link>` and attach it to the `<head>` which should solve your problem. It will also work cross-domain and is supported by all browsers made in the last decade.

```
function load_css(url) {
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.type = 'text/css';
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = url;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

Then just load your CSS like this:

```
load_css('/css/css.css');
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I need synchronous load because the code must load before script execution proceeds. I load two types of files: one var oNew = document.createElement("script"); and another var oNew = document.createElement('style');

I like your solution if it can get it to work synchronously.

Comment: I'm going to try using a que with "onload" event for "var link.onload=function(){processNextLink()}". Hoping it will work, will post an update.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution involved use of @idbehold's suggestion to appendChild() in header. There is a cycle that builds an array stack of all files that must be included. Then there are onLoad events added to every "link" element that check when it is last element in the stack then a global variable called isLoading in set to false. And then there is a check in main function call:
  if (isLoading){setTimeout(function(){ js2dx.init(data) }, 1);return;}

which will wait until all files load before proceeding. A very ugly solution. :(